# tesseractjs is returning weird result and extra characters

Tags: node.js

currently i'm trying to extract text from Instagram story using tesseractjs. But some image gave me weird result.

[image]

and i got this result

[image]

here is my nodejs code

```
const { createWorker } = require('tesseract.js');
const worker = createWorker();

async function test() {
    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
    await worker.initialize('eng');
    const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize('https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5VX0.jpg');
    console.log(text);

  await worker.terminate();
}

test();
```

Did anyone know why its returning extra and weird character? 
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract.js works much better with simple text, typical light-colored background text and dark text or vice versa.
I have problems with Tesseract.js when I try to extract text from images that are not simple or from a video or photographs.

That's why you can extract simple text from the top of the image, but the lower text is more difficult to understand, you can also interpret patterns as text erroneously

I recommend you read this article. https://yoric.github.io/post/extracting-text-from-images/
It made me look for more solutions to this problem than I also have when I use tesseract.js, I still can't find another request for local processes, but external APIs show better results. But in the end, the intention is not to depend on external services.

If you know a better solution, pass me the data.